# AngularJS: Controller variable not updating despite being bound to service variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**Problem:** A controller variable `vm.boatList` (intended to be bound to a service variable, `SearchService.boatList`) is not updating with the service variable.

**Code Snippets:** Complete code at the bottom.

*Controller*

```
function SearchController($stateParams, SearchService) {
        var vm = this;

        vm.boatList = SearchService.boatList;
```

*Service*

```
function SearchService(BoatsDataService) {

        var service = {
            boatList: null,
            getBoatList: getBoatList,
            params: {}
        };

        return service;
```

**Additional Data:**

The `getBoatList` function called from the controller works - it logs data from the `SearchService` to the console. When I log `vm.boatList` immediately afterward, it's null.

Also, `<div ng-repeat="boat in SearchController.boatList">...</div>` only works when I assign directly to `vm.boatList`.

**Console Output:**

```
Array[3]
null
```

**Complete Controller:**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.
        module('trips').
        controller('SearchController', SearchController);

    SearchController.$inject = ['$stateParams', 'SearchService'];

    function SearchController($stateParams, SearchService) {
        var vm = this;

        vm.boatList = SearchService.boatList;
        vm.initialParams = getParams();

        activate();

        ////////////////////

        function activate() {
            setInitialParams();
            SearchService.getBoatList()
                .then(function (data) {
                    SearchService.boatList = data;
                    console.log(SearchService.boatList);  // Logs data.
                    console.log(vm.boatList);  // Logs null.
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                });
        }

        function getParams() {
            var params = {
                location: $stateParams.location,
                passengers: $stateParams.passengers,
                maxPrice: $stateParams.maxPrice,
                minPrice: $stateParams.minPrice,
                embark: $stateParams.embark,
                disembark: $stateParams.disembark,
                category: $stateParams.category
            };
            return params;
        }

        function setInitialParams() {
            SearchService.params = getParams();
        }
    }
})();
```

**Complete Service:**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.
        module('trips').
        factory('SearchService', SearchService);

    SearchService.$inject = ['BoatsDataService'];

    function SearchService(BoatsDataService) {

        var service = {
            boatList: null,
            getBoatList: getBoatList,
            params: {}
        };

        //$scope.$watch('service.params', function () {
        //        getBoatList().then(function (data {
        //            service.boatList = data;
        //        })
        //    }, true
        //);

        return service;

        //////////////////////

        function getBoatList() {
            return BoatsDataService.BoatList
                .query(service.params)
                .$promise
        }
    }
})();
```

**Recap:** I don't know how to two-way bind, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're trying to bind a variable that's directly on the service, it will fail (see [call by sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_sharing)). However, if you wrap it with an object, it will work like you expect, see [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/18156/).

So in your case, if you bind an object inside the service to your controller, it should be fine -

Service:

```
var service = {
      boatListObj : {
            boatList: null
      },
      getBoatList: getBoatList,
      params: {}
};
```

Controller:

```
vm.boatListObj = SearchService.boatListObj;
```

Promise response:

```
.then(function (data) {
        SearchService.boatListObj.boatList = data;
        console.log(SearchService.boatListObj.boatList);  // Logs data.
        console.log(vm.boatListObj.boatList);  // Should log fine now
})
```

The reason why `<div ng-repeat="boat in SearchController.boatList">...</div>` is not working is because `SearchController.boatList` is not on the `$scope`. It either must be on the $scope, or addressed via ControllerAs syntax when it's placed on the controller.

Comment: This works, thanks! My follow-up is: **why doesn't `boatList = {}` work, since that creates an empty object?** In fact, when I use that syntax it logs to the console as an Object. My understanding based on some reading is that as long as the bound variable isn't a primitive, it would set up the automatic $watch.

Comment: It's not working because you're trying to override it when you're doing `boatList = ...` afterwards, meaning you're trying to change `boatList`'s reference. Notice that in the solution you're modifying a variable inside an object, and not changing the wrapper object to point to a different object.